# RecyclerView onScrollStateChanged/onScrolled event is not fired when no scrolling occurred

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

Doesn't sound like a problem, right?) Let me explain the use case. Let say at the end of every scroll event you want to animate/highlight the target item:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView,final int newState){
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView,newState);
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) { // on scroll stop
            blink();
        }
    }
}
...
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(targetPosition);
```

Works as expected, as long as current position is different from the target one and there is something to scroll actually. What is also very possible is that the list is already in the right position and calling `scrollToPosition()` has no effect, `onScrollStateChanged()` is not triggered, as well as our animation logic. As a workaround I can think about this:

```
final int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
if (firstVisibleItemPosition == targetPosition){
    blink();
} else {
    [previous code block]
}
```

but is it really the best possible solution? It sounds natural to me to have some consistent `onScrollStop()` callback after every `scrollToPosition()` call, regardless of the visual list movement, because it's none of my business to predict what is going to happen on the screen (will it move, or not?) and try to hack that. All I know, as an API user is that `scrollToPosition()` was called and I expect the appropriate callback to be fired.

Fun fact: if you extend `RecyclerView.SmoothScroller` and override `onStop()` method then you're actually notified all the time. The issue with this approach is that it's triggered slightly before the list stop scrolling ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: My onScrollStateChanged seems to be called with different states continually, even after the scrolling has stopped.  Looking for a solution for this.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I stuck with the same problem